# How to solve the following 1D second order ODE for y(x)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following 1D second order nonlinear ODE for $y(x)$:
$$y''=yy'+y^3 \tag{1}$$

For the following 1D second order nonlinear ODE for $z(x)$:

$$z''=3zz'-z^3 \tag{2}$$

Mathematica produces the closed-form solution:
$$z(x)=-\frac{2a(b+x)}{3+ab(b+2x)+ax^2}\tag{3}$$

Thanks!
-Mike

Setting $$y(x)=\frac{y_0}{1-b x}\tag{4}$$ into (1) we obtain $b=y_0$ and $b=-\tfrac12y_0$.

Mathematica apparently missed these solutions.

Comment: your $yy'$ is not correct.  It should be $\frac{b y_0^2}{(1-b x)^3}$

Comment: Totally right. Including your two $b\,.$ Will delete that misleading comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y\frac{dy}{dx}+y^3$$
This is an ODE of autonomous kind. The usual method for solving is :

Change of function : $\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=F(y)$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dF}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=F(y)\frac{dF}{dy}$$
The ODE is transformed to :
$$F(y)\frac{dF}{dy}=yF(y)+y^3$$
$$F\frac{dF}{ydy}=F+y^2$$
Change of variable : $\quad X=y^2$
$$2F\frac{dF}{dX}=F+X$$
This first order nonlinear ODE is solvable (with the help of WolframAlpha).
$$F(X)=\frac12\left(X+\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{c^2-cX^3}+2c-X^3}+\frac{X^2}{\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{c^2-cX^3}+2c-X^3}}\right)$$
Then one have to comeback to the variables $x,y$.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=F(y)\quad\implies\quad x(y)=\int \frac{dy}{F(y)}$
$$x(y)=\int \frac{dy}{\frac12\left(y^2+\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{c^2-cy^6}+2c-y^6}+\frac{y^4}{\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{c^2-cy^6}+2c-y^6}}\right)}+C$$
It is doubtful that this integral could be analytically solved. It is even more doubtful that the inverse function $y(x)$ could be derived. In practical application better use numerical calculus directly from the initial ODE.